# How to set a boolean field in Dynamo DB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, boolean, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to put a new entry into a DynamoDB table that has boolean value:

```
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});
ddb.putItem({
  "TableName": "states",
  "Item" : {
    "name": {"S": "california" },
    "coastal": {"BOOL": 1}
  }
})
```

But I'm getting:

```
Expected params.Item['coastal'].BOOL to be a boolean
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Duh, I realized I needed to actually make it a boolean:

```
"coastal": {"BOOL": False}
```